# Angular 2 Two way binding removes name attribute from html input tag

Tags: html, laravel-5, angular2-forms, angular-ngmodel

When I am two way binding in input tag, name attribute gets removed from input tag. A binding element is an array.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let box of boxs; let boxindex=index ">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label>Boxs</label>
<input type="text" name="count[{{boxindex}}]" [(ngModel)]="box[boxindex]">
</div>
</div>
```

When I am writing in above way name attribute get removed but

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let box of boxs; let boxindex=index ">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<label>Boxs</label>
<input type="text" name="count[]" [(ngModel)]="box[boxindex]">
</div>
</div>
```

in this way name attribute remains. What is Wrong in first code?
I am Posting this form to Laravel Route.

Comment: did you tried `name="count[boxindex]"` ??

Comment: Tried didn't work HTML input takes 'boxindex' as key name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your initial code like this

```
<div *ngFor="let box of boxs; let boxindex=index ">
  <div>
   <label>Boxs</label>
   <input #input type="text" name="count[{{boxindex}}]" placeholder={{input.name}}>
  </div>
</div>
```

[on plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/boT1fbabiboG5QGr3N13?p=preview) and it's working, should be something else taking out your name.

### Edit

I tried the same code with 2.0.0 an is working. Although I don't know how the code you displayed here is working, because on 2.0.0 angular was not accepting `let` on `*ngFor` but `#`

```
<div *ngFor="#box of boxs; #boxindex=index ">
```

You can find the working plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/BF7UmSWddHwoS6P94Ntl?p=preview)

My strong advice for you is to upgrade your 2.0.0 solution to a recent version of Angular.

Comment: Is there any version compatibility because my angular version is 2.0.

Comment: Which  exact version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Angular Version
 `@angular/cli: 1.1.2
node: 8.1.2
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.0.0
@angular/compiler: 2.0.0
@angular/core: 2.0.0
@angular/forms: 2.0.0
@angular/http: 2.0.0
@angular/platform-browser: 2.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.0.0
@angular/router: 3.0.0
`

Comment: @Zeal Nagar - I edited the response after the tests with angular 2.0.0